# returning promises chai as promised

Tags: protractor, angular-promise, chai, chai-as-promised

I am new to promises,  I have the following function

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

it('should do something with promises', function() {
    var blah = 'foo';

    var result = systemUnderTest();

    return expect(result).to.eventually.equal(blah);
});
```

why there is `return` keyword before `expect` , what is the significance of it and what would happen if we don't `return`

Answer (score 0):

You must return the promise to execute all the promise chain

```
it('should do something with promises', function() {
    const expected = "test";
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ...//Something to do
    });
    promise.then(() => {
        return expected;
    });
    return expect(promise).to.eventually.equal(expected);
});
```

If you don't return the promise then the block `then` could be executed after the expect evaluation;